# Absolute element inside table is causing the table to enable overflow-y: scroll somehow

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, css-tables

I have a table with some services. Each service has a "?"-icon that the visitor can click to read more info about the service.

**See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98jpn0uh/7/)**

---

The table's wrapper has:

```
@media all and (max-width: 560px) {
    .table-wrapper {
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}
```

So you can easily scroll to the right or left on mobile devices (because the table is too wide for small screens).

But here's the problem: some of the popups (especially the last one) are causing the table's wrapper to scroll vertically, while it doesn't have "overflow-y: scroll" !

Because of the popups there appears a scrollbar and you can scroll inside the table... that's not what I want :(
So when you view this table on mobile devices you can't scroll down the page anymore because the table is in the way.

**Here's what I do want:** the popups have "z-index: 1;" so the popups will be on top of almost all other elements. So the popup should also hover above elements below (and outside the table). The table height should basically be the same as it's wrapper, but the popup need to be able to flow over the edges of this wrapper (and table). I thought that was automatically done thanks to it's "position: absolute;" but that was not the case.

---

**UPDATE:**

Really ugly solution: set a margin-bottom to the table equal or larger to the last and highest popup, so the table-wrapper will not need a vertical scrollbar. But like I said: really ugly.

---

**See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98jpn0uh/7/)**

---

**UPDATE** (minor)**:** I only set "overflow-x: auto" on the wrapper when the table is larger than the screen (approx. 560px), so the problem won't show on desktops.

---

Comment: try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2y800kco/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT2**
Checkout this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2y800kco/1/)
I think it's working now :)

**EDIT**

[image]

if you want to hide the vertical scrollbar that shows when screen `width` is < `560px` then you can simply disable it using `overflow-y:hidden` and to show the popup over other elements following the table you can set `height:100%` in you `@media` query

```
@media all and (max-width: 560px) {
  .table-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;  // <-- 
    height:100%;        // <--
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
}
```

And to hide the space after the table you can't set the next element to a *negative* `margin-top`
like this

```
div_after_the_table {
margin-top:-75px;
}
```

Comment: No because when I do that, the popup cuts in half :p that's not what i want. I want it to overflow without scroll

Comment: if i'm understanding, the phenomena is that the popup scrolls ? not the table body ?

Comment: If you would take a look at the fiddle inside my question you can see that because of the popup, the table-wrapper suddenly starts to show a scrollbar on the y-axis as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help, m8. You can see my fiddle in the answer I just posted to really see what I meant. I also did margin-top negative and used overflow hidden, so I am gonna upvote your answer and thank you once more for your time. Happy coding!

Comment: allright I thought I fixed it, but it's not! I'm going to try your way now! ;o

Comment: my way is the one ;p i promise

Comment: Could you maybe edit my fiddle, safe it and post a link? I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Allright, I get it now! But there's a problem: the scrollbar is now on top of the elements after the table. But I could hide it and create a custom scrollbar i guess. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: I now have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98jpn0uh/37/) but as you can see, I'm having problems with the scrollbar now...

Comment: Allright I fixed it: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98jpn0uh/38/) I'll post an answer

Comment: I posted an answer, hope you like it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122429/discussion-between-moolsbytheway-and-derk-jan-speelman).

Answer (score 1):

```css
div .more-info {
    position: static;
}
```

The immediate parent of the absolute popup has to be positioned `static` in order to get it out of the table scroll.

I have been working for the same kind of issue, but my issue still unresolved. I have set icon `position:absolute` to show it to the right of the 1st column without wrapping it to next line. But problem occurs with popup positioning with the icon when the parent has been positioned static.

In your case, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your table in another div with `position: absolute;`, the popups will be able to display outside of the overflow.

Comment: obviously what happens than is that the entire table is absolute and the height is basically screwed up, because the table is absolute :p